# curve_fit function not fitting to original data perfectly

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I have a set of data and I fitted my data with the curve_fit function 
 but the line does not describe the original dataset good enough. 
 The curve_fit function is not close to the orginal data.

the `x`  array has following data:

```
[0. 0.025 0.10333333 0.1175 0.164 0.22 0.27571429 0.27625 0.33333333 0.379 0.40545455 0.43416667 0.47769231 0.52571429 0.528 0.538125 0.56470588 0.5577777 0.59263158 0.6065 0.61190476 0.62545455 ...]
```

`y` array looks like this:

```
[1. 1.95 2.83 3.73 4.57 5.32 5.97 6.81 7.35 7.86 8.5 9.09 9.4 9.83 10.41 11. 11.34 11.8  ...]
```

My `curve_fit func`:

```
def func(x, a, b, c,):
   return a*np.exp(-b*x)+c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,x,y, maxfev=10000)

plt.plot(x, y, ls="none", marker='.', color='grey')
plt.plot(x,func(x, *popt),'-')

plt.title("my curve")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Below is my plot:
[image]

Comment: One could think about weighting the fit by the inverse of the point density. Also one could fit x(y) instead of y(x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see you are trying to fit an exponential curve to your data. Most of your data is concentrated on the upper right and hence the algorithm tries to fit it best-possible to that part.

Comment: thanks , but how can I fit my curve for the lower left part?

Comment: If you know that your data will look like the example you've provided, I suggest using a polynomial model and a least-squares fit. This works reasonably well in practice.

Edit: If you insist on an exponential model, maybe logarithmize your data and try a linear model then.